# Powershell output single value

Tags: powershell

I have the following issue. I want to output my default printer name to a .txt-file for use in another script to set this printer as default for other computers. the query I use is:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_printer where default=$true"
```

it gives me this data:

```
Location      : xxxx
Name          : \\printserver\nameofprinter
PrinterState  : 0
PrinterStatus : 3
ShareName     : nameofprinter
SystemName    : \\printserver
```

But I want the query to give me only the value for "Name" when i Out-File it. so far i have used Format-List -Property Name. But this outputs the whole line. I only want the "\Printerserver\nameofprinter" in my outfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_printer where default=$true" | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_printer where default=$true" | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

OR

```
(Get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_printer where default=$true").Name
```

Will do what you want.

Hope this helps

EDIT:
As you only wanted to write a file IF a printer exists, try something like the following (tested with printer, but I'm not uninstalling all my printers to test without!)

```
if ( $printerName = (Get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_printer where default=$true").Name ) { New-Item "C:\folder\printer.txt" -type file -Value $printerName -force }
```

Comment: Thanks! They both worked great! it sometimes however is a small problem with it. the default printer could not be set, hence leaving the out-file blank, is there a way to prevent the query from giving a blank result?

(more like preventing the out-file to even be edited/made if the result of the query gives no data)

/Niklas

Comment: Have ammended my answer